# can I use same cache name for methods in different class for caching using ehcache

Tags: ehcache

I have created two methods in different classes and annotated them with `@Cacheable` annotation and given same cache name as below:

```
class MyClass{
    @Cacheable(value="inScopeCache")
    public Products getProducts() { 
        //reading data from repository
    } 
}

class MyNewClass{
    @Cacheable(value="inScopeCache")
    public NewProducts getProducts() { 
        //reading data from repository..
    } 
}
```

Will it work? if yes then how?
I have defined the above cache in spring xml properly.
What will happen if both methods would be invoked at same time?

How would key generate for this case as there is no parameter for this method?

thanks
Harish

Comment: will it overwrite the inScopeCache with the later creating?

When cache will be got created during startup or when we call this particular method?

Answer (score 4):

This will not work, not because of the cache names being identical, but because of the no arg methods.

[Spring Caching's default key generation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key) will end up using the same key for both methods, thus causing collision inside the cache.

You have two options:

1. Specify the key to be used in each method
2. Use different caches

Comment: Thanks Louis for clarification, but it should work if I am hitting only one method because as per my understanding cache will be initialized when first time this any of these two method would be invoked? and no collision will be occured as second method will not be invoked any more?